# How to design a Restful API with the resource hierarchy?

Tags: rest, uri, restful-url

There are products and reviews of products.
So, I can get product list like this...

```
GET /products
```

also I can fetch one product or reviews or the product like this...

```
GET /products/{productID}
GET /products/{productID}/reviews
```

Those are clear. but the problem happens when I want to get all reviews I wrote.
I could create uri like this..

```
1. GET /products/reviews?author=myId
```

or

```
2. GET /reviews?author=myID
```

However, the problem of first one comes from conflict between `{productID}` and reviews.
the problem of next one comes from relation products and reviews because reviews should be under the products according to the hierarchy.

How can I get all reviews I wrote with `RESTful` API?

Answer (score 0):

usually the route is like this

GET /products/:product_id/reviews?author=myID

so the parameters are 
  - product_id
  - author

with that, you will get all the reviews for a certain product and author.

Though, if you want all of your reviews, then this is correct:

GET /reviews?author=myID

Answer (score 0):

To get all reviews written by a given author for **all** products, a RESTful way to do this would be

GET /authors/{authorId}/reviews

If you want to get all reviews written by a given author for a **single** product, then you could use

(a)  GET /authors/{authorId}/products/{productId}/reviews

I like this approach over specifying productId or authorId in the query string.  Authors contain products, and products contain reviews, so this is a nice RESTful URL.  But if you want to use query string, then you could use either of the following:

(b) GET /products/{productId}/reviews?authorId={authorId}

(c) GET /authors/{authorId}/reviews?productId={productId}

But I personally prefer option (a) over options (b) or (c).  I think it describes the object hierarchy in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the second one if I were you, since flat URIs are usually shorter than hierarchical ones and shorter URIs are easier to route: it is harder to mistype the URI template accidentally.

So using

- `GET /reviews?author={myID}`
- `GET /reviews?product={productID}`

is ok too. (If you have different review types, maybe it is better to use `product-reviews` instead of just `reviews`.)

Just to avoid misunderstandings REST does not have URI structure constraints, those are implementation details, so you can use both your proposed URIs. You should document them and apply the HATEOAS constraint.